# Maven BOM file multi module project

Tags: maven-3, maven-versions-plugin

With Maven BOM (Bill of materials) file I could able to use dependencies without defining versions of dependencies in POMs by importing this BOM as below

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyOwn-BOM</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

As I have used in multiple projects. I wanted to use [Maven Version Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) to change version of all modules using this BOM file at once, but no luck.

Any help is appreciable.